# Which schools of Hinduism or acharyas have Hinduism believed that the Vedas were authored by the Rishis?

Tags: vedas, apaurusheyatva

Vedanta and Purva Mimamsa believe that the Vedas are unauthored. Nyaya believes that the Vedas are authored by Ishvara.

What do other sects believe? Is there anyone that believes that the Rishis authored the Vedas?

Here are some verses:

> RV 1.61.4: asmā idu stomaṃ saṃ hinomi rathaṃ na taṣṭeva — “For him, **I
> design this hymn**, just as a carpenter designs a chariot”
>
> RV 1.77.1: kathā dāśemāgnaye kāsmai devajuṣṭocyate bhāmine gīḥ — “How
> shall we offer to Agni, **what kind of words should we say** to him the
> bright one, which will be divinely acceptable?”
>
> RV 1.94.1: imaṃ stomamarhate jātavedase rathamiva saṃ mahemā manīṣayā
> — “**This stotra we make** for the most sacred Jātaveda with deep
> meditation, just like building a chariot”

Comment: By definition, all Hindus follow the vedas. The vedas say that the vedas were revealed to the rishis. See Brahma Sutras I.3.29 and Rig Veda 10.71.3 - "By means of their past good deeds (the priests) attained the capacity to understand the Vedas; (then) they found them dwelling in the Rsis" The vedas are eternal and from God - they were revealed by the Rishis

Comment: I could explain something to you put this isn’t the correct place.

Comment: If anyone is authoring the Vedas wouldn't, the constantly referred to as people, Vedas be a more obvious choice. It's not like works named after their authors are a rare thing in Hinduism.